# Внесение и преобразование элементов одномерного текстового массива C#

Tags: c#, массивы, winforms, динамические-массивы, datagridview

Всем привет. Вопрос по *C# (Windows Form)*. Помогите коректно составить код относительно задания. В данный момент работает только часть с вводом информации в *DG1*. Укажите, как правильно все устаканить, чтобы код работал. Если во 2-м пункте правильнее будет использовать *TextChanged* для считывания информации в массив - помогите реализовать это. Ну и в целом, если мои наработки не подходят для решения задачи - укажите на это.

Буду благодарен за любые конструктивные комментарии и помощь, которые могут помочь решить эту задачу.

Задание состоит в том, чтобы с помощью *TextBox'a* сформировать масив с произвольной текстовой информацией (*пример: щука, конь, кот, собака, павлин...*) после чего этот массив должен перейти в *DataGridView1* с помощью *Button1*. Далее необходимо изменить порядок введенной информации в массив на обратный (*относительно примера: павлин, собака, кот, конь, щука...*) и, соответственно, вывести его в *DataGridView2* с помощью *Button2*.
Для наглядности, прикладываю изображение интерфейса [image: изображение интерфейса]

По структуре решения необходимо было создать:

1. Класс, который включает в себя размерности, индексатор и один метод, который отвечает за изменение порядка массива на обратный.
2. На событие (нажатие *Button1*) - внесение текстовой информации в массив и ее перемещение в *DG1*.
3. На событие (нажатие *Button2*) - вызов метода класса, который отвечает за изменение порядка массива на обратный и внесение его в *DG2*.

По коду разработал:
1)

```
class LN
        {
            public bool error = false;
            string[] A;
            int length;
            public LN(int size)
            { A = new string[size]; length = size; }
            public int Length
            {
                get
                {
                    return length;
                }
            }
            public string [] B // метод преобразования массива в обратный порядок
            {
                get
                {
                    string[] A = new string[length];
                    for (int i = length -1; i >= 0; i--);
                    return new string[length];
                }
            }

            public string this[int i] // индексатор
            { get { if (i >= 0 && i < length) return A[i];
            else { error = true; return "0"; }
            }
            set { if (i >= 0 && i < length) A[i] = value;
            else error = true;
            }
        }
```

2. 

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                string[] A = new string[1];
                for (int i = 0; i <= (A.Length - 1); i++)
                {
                    A[i] = Convert.ToString(textBox1.Text);
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(A[i].ToString());
                }     
        }
```

3. 

```
private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                B[i] = Convert.ToString();
                dataGridView2.Rows.Add(B[i].ToString());
        }
```

Comment: Ну то есть у вас есть какой то класс, что вы не используете и 2 куска какого то кода , которые не работают. В чем заключается ваш вопрос?

Comment: `с помощью TextBox'a сформировать масив с произвольной текстовой информацией (пример: щука, конь, кот, собака, павлин...)` где эта часть в вашем коде?

Comment: Добрый вечер. Вопрос заключается в том, как соединить эти части, если в них имеется какой-то смысл. Что касается TextBox'a - эта часть во втором отрезке, но слова с примера указываются в самой форме. Мне действительно не хватает опыта, чтобы полноценно разобраться, как все элементы должны работать вместе, поэтому и написал этот вопрос.

Comment: Второй отрезок мне в принципе непонятен. Там же нет текстбокса. Там что то непонятное пишется в какой то непонятный массив по непонятному индексу и результат добавляется в грид.

Comment: У вас должна быть форма с нужными элементами управления на ней и два обработчика кнопок -по одному на кнопку

Comment: Обработчики должны делать именно то, что указано в задании, и не больше того. Написано разделение текста на слова - делите текст на слова. Где это у вас? Этого у вас нет. Чтобы текст разделит на слова, нужно понять, по какому принципу это делать - делит по пробелам или переносом строк. После этого воспользоваться методом строки  Split

Comment: Благодарю за объяснения. А вы не могли бы указать, где конкретно я могу ознакомиться с элементами проблематики моего задания (или по каким ключевым словам). В моем примере, обработчик первой кнопки просто вводит одно значение в DG1 (при нажатии ентера) и так можно делать множество раз.  Но я хочу верить, что я Вас понял. Поищу, но в целом принцип разделения - в условиях задачи не важен. И, если у Вас будет возможность и желание, не могли бы продемонстрировать, как это правильно делается. Еще раз спасибо.

Comment: ну, например, вы можете ваш первый обработчик нписать как то так `for (var word in mytextbox.Text.Split()) mygridview.rows.add(word);` - что то подобное будет явно говорить, что вы берете текст из текстбокса, делите на слова, пишете слова в грид в порядке, каком они в текстбоксе. Если я верно понял, это то, что вам и надо, верно?

Comment: Да, именно то. Вторая же часть заключается в том, чтобы обернуть порядок значений этого же массива на обратный (и по аналогии с 1-м вывести, но в другой DG)

Comment: ну то есть что то типа `for (var word in mytextbox.Text.Split().Reverse()) mygridview.rows.add(word);` ? То же, что и предыдущий раз, но список слов обработать в обратном порядке?

Comment: Да, оно. Если это так просто записывается. Но по словам - да. А как это в совокупности должно все выглядеть?

Comment: это и есть вся совокупность. Вам теперь надо понять, что это код делает и запустить его в нужных обработчиках для нужных гридов, и все по сути.

Comment: назначение этого `Класс, который включает в себя размерности, индексатор и один метод, который отвечает за изменение порядка массива на обратный.` в вашем задании я не понял.

Comment: Это просто нечто, спасибо большое. Действительно так просто. Все что было - это результат длительных поисков и смешивания чего попало. Вопрос один появился, оно оставляет одну пустую ячейку между результатами (где "..." - пробелы, по типу:
ABC
...
CDC
...
GGG

Это каким-то образом регулируется?

Спасибо Вам большое, если хотите можете указать эти 2-е строчки, как ответ - я подтвержу его :)

Comment: Хотя все, дополнительный вопрос отпал, я multiline оставил и через энтеры вводил. Спасибо большое

Comment: отправил ответом, отмечайте только если уверены, что вашу задачу это решило.

Comment: Решило, я все протестировал, правда остался в шоке, что это действительно можно было сделать так просто

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> с помощью TextBox'a сформировать масив с произвольной текстовой информацией (пример: щука, конь, кот, собака, павлин...) после чего этот массив должен перейти в DataGridView1 с помощью Button1

```
for (var word in mytextbox.Text.Split()) 
    mygridview.rows.add(word);
```

> Далее необходимо изменить порядок введенной информации в массив на обратный (относительно примера: павлин, собака, кот, конь, щука...) и, соответственно, вывести его в DataGridView2 с помощью Button2.

```
for (var word in mytextbox.Text.Split().Reverse()) 
    mygridview2.rows.add(word);
```